# Model refuses to move in pose mode

Tags: bones, weight-painting, pose-mode

I'm working on a model for the VR game for school. But for some reason it refuses to move. Before it was working fine then I had to fix the tail and now it refuses to do anything. the weight painting is ok. noting is locked. the model works but it just refuses to turn the bones in pose mode... is there a fix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested a bit longer my hole rotation tool doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foun the problem myself with the help of a teacher 
[image]